# Late on mortgage: Can the bank disclose this to my mortgage broker?

Tags: mortgage

I was late on my mortgage payment with Bank of America for a couple of months.  Does BOA have the right to disclose this with the company that helped me obtain my mortgage?

Comment: Kerri - I've never heard of a broker being kept in the loop by a lender. Once the deal is closed, most brokers tend to have nothing to do with the situation, so my reaction is no, there's no business reason for BoA to tell them. Having said that, Vitalik (below) is right - two months and it's public knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of months? well it will probably end up on your credit report and then it's available to pretty much anybody.

Comment: Yep, anything more than 30 days is the rule of thumb.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but I think this probably depends on what's in your mortgage contract.  I'm not aware of any laws that would prevent this.  US courts have held that mortgagors have no constitutional right to privacy against a lender's disclosure of records (see 959 F.Supp. 478), and this would not be considered a **public** disclosure of private facts which could be actionable.